# Connecting to s3 bucket with Media Library Strapi

Tags: amazon-s3, strapi, media-library

I've used Strapi for a while as a headless cms and, in their most recent update, they changed the File Upload plugin to Media Library. You used to be able to connect an s3 bucket to your app via File Upload's settings- does anyone have any idea how you do the same thing now that Media Library has replaced it?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using strapi version 3.0.0-beta.20.x

What you have to do is to create a settings.json file with below config

`./extensions/upload/config/settings.json`

```
{
  "provider": "aws-s3",
  "providerOptions": {
    "accessKeyId": "dev-key",
    "secretAccessKey": "dev-secret",
    "region": "aws-region",
    "params": {
      "Bucket": "my-bucket"
    }
  }
}
```

You can check out the [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/strapi-provider-upload-aws-s3) for more details